# how to set background image in uitableview cell in ios7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am new to ios and now a days i am facing a little issue.When table view load then after scrolling up and down then background image show [like this](http://screencast.com/t/G4MK09D31K) and here is my code

Actually i want to show table as chat design. i not want to use any third party.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [_messages count];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *comment = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGFloat whidt =  250;
UIFont *FONT = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];
NSAttributedString *attributedText =[[NSAttributedString alloc]  initWithString:comment  attributes:@  {      NSFontAttributeName: FONT }];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){whidt, MAXFLOAT}
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
return size.height +50;

}


- (UIFont *)fontForCell{
return [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChatListItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

NSString *text = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(250 , 20000.0f);
UIFont *FONT = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
CGSize size = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:FONT }context:nil].size;

cell.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 250, MAX(size.height, 54.0f) + 20.0f);
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.textLabel.text = text;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:18];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon_selected_right.png"];
CGSize imgSize = cell.textLabel.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
[img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,250,imgSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];

/*[cell.textLabel setText:[_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
cell.textLabel.text = [_messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];*/

return cell;
}
```

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a custom delegate method for this. here is the solution of your proble ...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell in each row
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];

    UILabel *textLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    [textLabel setText:@""];

    textLabel.text = @"some text message to show"; // your text string
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)getCellContentView:(NSString *)cellIdentifier
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    CGRect labelRect = CGRectMake(20, 5, 100, 30); // set your desired values here
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    CGSize imgSize = labelRect.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( imgSize );
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,250,imgSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelRect];
    textLabel.tag=1;
    textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Superclarendon" size:15];
    // some of your other constraints to set ... 
    textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:textLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use resizableImageWithCapInsets,

```
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"baloonImage"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0,10.0,5.0,10.0)];
 [self.yourButton setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Modify the values (UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)) to suit any image you need.

Above code will make the image corners fixed and then after you can resize the image frame to adjust your view size,

```
 [image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: thanks but your solution not work [see this](http://screencast.com/t/xtFxqHDa) `UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"balloon_selected_right.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0,15.0,10.0,10.0)];
    [cell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250,size.height)];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img];`

Comment: did you set image frame after this code?? e.g.[image setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];

Answer (score 0):

Haseeb, based on this line of code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
```

I can see that you are not using custom table view cells.

I think the best way to solve this would be to use a custom table view cell. You would create your own class where you could design your own cell.

Comment: can you provide ma sample code but i not want to use any third party.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5hyy2JfuXko) for tutorials. Custom cells are very useful so learning how to use them properly will really help rather than using quick code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways of doing this:  1) create a custom UITableViewCell (lots of examples on the net on how to do this), 2) you could also simply add your image as a Layer to the cell (again, lots of examples).

For example:

```
ImageTableViewCell : UITAbleViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *backgroundImage;
```

Then, in your implementation something like this:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CALayer *imageLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
    imageLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;

    // code goes here to do whatever you want to the image ...

    imageLayer.contents = self.backgroundImage.CGImage;
    [self.layer addSublayer:imageLayer];
}
```

Food for thought, as they say ....

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above use a custom prototype cell.  Then in the Document Outline select the prototype cell and the Attributes inspector. Under View put Alpha to 0 Background color to Clear Color.

Comment: Could you please add more details about the solution you provide?

Comment: In ViewController.swift `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`              `let backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: “Sunset”))`    `override func viewDidLoad() {`                                                                         `super.viewDidLoad()`                                                                                       `backgroundImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill`                                     `tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImage`

Answer (score 0):

In swift you can set background image to UITableViewCell like below.

```
cell.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage.png")!)
```

Write this code in this function of table view.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This image will repeat fort each row.